# How to get iframe html from diff origin

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="http://libs.baidu.com/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="1" src="https://bing.com" frameborder="2" height="300px" width="800px"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

When i type $('#1').contents() in chrome console, it raise:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:63342" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

my question is: How to get the html of iframe(I found exist question can't fix my question)

Comment: I should imagine it's not actually possible due to the "same origin policy"

Answer (score 1):

> my question is: How to get the html of iframe(I found exist question can't fix my question)

If the exist question said "you can't do that", then the exist answer is correct

However, if the site you wish to read has CORS set, then you could read the raw html (not from the iframe though)

There is a possibility by using a browser add-on, but I'm guessing you don't want to do this too obviously, i.e. instruct visitors to your site to download and install a browser add on

Comment: I successfully do it with selenium#within_frame, I hope to know how to do it in chrome conosle. Maybe exist more easy way except install addon